# initlializer element is not constant

Tags: objective-c, xcode

guys i m getting this basic error "initializer element is not constant"..not able to figure where exactly i failed .below is the code.`

```
@implementation myfirstflickrappViewController

NSString *const FlickrAPIKey = @"14c39d71001b0fb84d1dacb6049580ec";

NSString *const text = @"hello";

NSString *urlString = 
[NSString stringWithFormat:
 @"http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=%@&tags=%@&per_page=25&format=json&nojsoncallback=1", 
 FlickrAPIKey, text];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call a method on `NSString` (s`tringWithFormat:`) in a place where you are not allowed to do so - namely outside of a method or function. Only constant expressions like string literals are allowed there.

You might put that code in your `-init` method or the class initializer.